# Why does For loop duplicates values

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to get some values from the server, everything is working fine however for some reason I receive the value as a duplicate, the server contains of 3 keys and values however in my code it shows 6 keys and values, please advise what could be causing this.

FirstActivity.java

```
public void getGifts() {
    Communicator.getInstance().on("initializeRoom", new Emitter.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            JSONDictionary response = (JSONDictionary) args[0];
            String str = response.get("data").toString();
            try {
                JSONObject dataJSo = new JSONObject(str);
                JSONArray giftsData = dataJSo.getJSONArray("gifts");
                for (int i = 0; i < giftsData.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject gifts = (JSONObject) giftsData.get(i);
                    giftsId = (Integer) gifts.get("id");
                    giftsPrice = (Integer) gifts.get("price");
                    giftsMinLevel = (String) gifts.get("minLevel");
                    giftsUrl = (String) gifts.get("urlFile");
                    giftsArray.add(new GiftsModel(giftsId, giftsPrice, 
                                    giftsUrl, giftsMinLevel));

                }

                Singleton.instance().cache = giftsArray;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity{

      ArrayList<GiftsModel> giftsArray = Singleton.instance().cache;

      //And some code

}
```

Singleton.java

```
public class Singleton {
private Singleton() {}

static Singleton obj= null;
public static Singleton instance() {
    if (obj == null) {
        obj = new Singleton();
    }
    return obj;
}

public ArrayList<GiftsModel> cache;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you expect the singleton to be doing here.  This could be the reason for your observed behavior.

Comment: can you share what is inside str variable?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm expecting to pass the arraylist from one class to another, I've updated my code with the SIngleton class

Comment: OT: avoid singeltons: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/634723/singletons-why-are-they-bad

Comment: perhaps your `giftsArray` is not cleared before adding new values, you can add log statement in order analyse it further what causing the duplication.

Comment: @Fahadsk dude,,,thank you so much for your comment, now it has been solved (Y)